# OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener of custom preference

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I created a class which extends android.support.v7.preference to make a custom preference then I include it in my preference.XML file.
I implement SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in my MainActivity and  @Override onSharedPreferenceChanged the default preference trigger the function but the custom preference didn't.
can anyone help

You can check out all the project from [here](https://github.com/MomenAli/CustomPreference)

this is my custom preference class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.preference.Preference;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceViewHolder;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class SeekbarPreference extends Preference  {

    private static final String TAG = "SeekbarPreference";

    public SeekbarPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setLayoutResource(R.layout.seekbar_preferences);

    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder);
        holder.itemView.setClickable(false);
        SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) holder.findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        final TextView tvSummary = (TextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.tvSummary);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                tvSummary.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
                Log.d(TAG, "onProgressChanged: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onStartTrackingTouch: ");

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onStopTrackingTouch: ");

            }
        });

    }
}
```

MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    private static final String SWITCH_ON_SHARED_KEY = "switchON";

    private static final String CHECK_SHARED_KEY = "allUsers";

    private static final String SEEKBAR_SHARED_KEY = "Seekbar_after";
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setupSharedPreferences();
    }

    private void setupSharedPreferences() {
        // Get all of the values from shared preferences to set it up
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


        sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.setting_item) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onSharedPreferenceChanged: " + key);
    }
}
```

my preference.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:defaultValue="@bool/default_switch"
        android:key="switchON"
        android:summaryOff="@string/hidden_text"
        android:summaryOn="@string/shown_text"
        android:title="Mode ON" />
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Decorate">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="@bool/default_check"
            android:key="allUsers"
            android:summaryOff="@string/hidden_text"
            android:summaryOn="@string/shown_text"
            android:title="All" />


        <com.example.momenali.custompreference.SeekbarPreference
            android:defaultValue="light"
            android:key="Seekbar_after" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: If you have the relevant code post it in your question, with comments where its going wrong or the current behaviour and expected behaviour.

Comment: Provide some codes pls.

Comment: Is This Code Clear ? @MarkKeen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching I figured out the solution.

and this is the project after updating [here](https://github.com/MomenAli/CustomPreference)

To trigger the listener and save the data I need to call the persistInt() function in the seekbarPreference class

```
public SeekbarPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setLayoutResource(R.layout.seekbar_preferences);

    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder);
        holder.itemView.setClickable(false);
        SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) holder.findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        final TextView tvSummary = (TextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.tvSummary);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                tvSummary.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
                Log.d(TAG, "onProgressChanged: ");
                persistInt(progress);               // call the persistInt function to save the data
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onStartTrackingTouch: ");

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onStopTrackingTouch: ");

            }
        });

    }
}
```

after calling persistInt the seekbar progress value saved but when we reopen setting the seekbar value still the default value

so we need to override onSetInitialValue() function to get the saved data as below

```
  @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restorePersistedValue, Object defaultValue) {
        super.onSetInitialValue(restorePersistedValue, defaultValue);
        if (restorePersistedValue){
            presentValue = getPersistedInt(0);
            Log.d(TAG, "SeekbarPreference: "+ presentValue );
        }else{
            presentValue = 5;
        }

    }
```

then we can update the progress value of the seekbar in the onBindViewHolder function